# VB.NET Windows Form show Keyboard numeric

Tags: vb.net, touch

I have a project Windows Forms VB.NET with some textbox.
This program work in table touch screen with windows 10.
I wuold like to show in some textbox the keyboard with only numbers.
There is possibility to set in a textbox to show a keyboard numerics when the user click on them?

Thanks

Comment: Either you use the OSK built into Windows, which you can research for yourself, or you build something yourself, which you can research for yourself. Either way, you need to make some sort of effort first and then post here if and when you encounter an actual issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could create a new form with 10 buttons (from 0 to 9)
each button text is corresponding with its value
then add this code to the new form:

```
Private Sub buttons(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn0.Click, Btn1.Click, Btn2.Click, Btn3.Click, Btn4.Click, Btn5.Click, Btn6.Click, Btn7.Click, Btn8.Click, Btn9.Click

    If yourtextbox.Text = "" Then
        yourtextbox.Text = sender.text
    Else yourtextbox.Text = yourtextbox.Text & sender.text
    End If

End Sub
```

under yourtextbox mouse click event

```
newform.show()
```

Comment: Yes, I've create a new form whit 10 button and I get the value in my main form. Thanks

Comment: @Simone, glad to know that your problem is solved, if you found this useful mark it as answer (the mark on the left of the answer), so that the topic will be closed

Answer (score 0):

There is a library that someone built that implements an undocumented COM interop to handle Window's on screen keyboard (aka OSK). The project can be found here: https://github.com/AlexeiScherbakov/osklib and can also be installed via NuGet.

Using this library you can bind the code that launches the OSK to the textbox by calling:

```
OnScreenKeyboardSettings.EnableForTextBox(TextBox1)
```

This does not open the numeric only keyboard by default. Instead the user would need to change the keyboard using the OSK and you would need to validate that the input afterwards.